# What is best pattern to reuse Go interface without tripping cyclic dependencies

Tags: go, design-patterns

I have this simple package declaration where package "a" defines an interface "A" but I need to use the interface in package "b" for type inference and then the implementation of `b.Request()` in `DoRequest()` of "a" this means having to import the package in a cyclic way.

My question is if there is a none complicated approach to this design to avoid compiler cyclic dependency error ?.

NOTE to avoid putting "a" and "b" in the same package

```
package b

import "a"

func Request(t a.A){
m := t.GetMethod()
payload := t.GetPayload()
}
```

And Package "a" declaration

```
package a

import "b"


type A interface {
 GetMethod () string
 GetPayload () string
}

type ImplementA struct {
}

func (imp ImplementA)GetMethod() string{
return ""
}

func (imp  ImplementA) GetPayload() string{
return ""
}

func (imp ImplementA) DoRequest(){
  b.Request(imp)
}
```

Comment: Define interface in package `b`.

Comment: The problem with that is that if "ImplimentA" adds a method, then package "b" needs to include the signature in it interface.  Would love be this to be implemented in a single place. I have though of another package for just type definition, but it seems useless in the context of the design

Comment: Any new method will have to change the interface anyway. You don't have to put the interface into package `a`. You can define and redefine the interface wherever it is used. If you want a common interface, use a third package containing the interface. One way of doing it is have package `a` declare the interface, and `a/impl` declare the implementation

Comment: My mind does not agree with defining interface in `b` but after thinking about it I will go with that decision. Thanks, hopefully it will not introduce more complexity and duplication as the codebase grows

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's spelled "Impl**e**ment" - not "impliment" :..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is considered best practice in go to define interfaces where they are used. So in `package b`, define an interface with those methods required by the function in `package b`.

You can still add other functions in `package a`. The interface from `package b` can be embedded if you also need to define an interface in `package a`.

For example:

```go
package b

type AInterface interface {
  GetMethod () string
  GetPayload () string
}

func Request(t AInterface) {
  m := t.GetMethod()
  payload := t.GetPayload()
}
```

Then package A would just contain the implementation.

```go
package a

import "b"

type ImplementA struct {
}

func (imp ImplementA) GetMethod() string {
  return ""
}

func (imp ImplementA) GetPayload() string {
  return ""
}

func (imp ImplementA) DoRequest() {
  b.Request(imp)
}
```